# Resource not found exception while trying to add recylerview to a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add a `recyclerview` to a `fragment`, but somehow there happens to be an error in the `adapter`.

I think it is the way in which I bind it, and I can't figure out the solution to it. Can anybody help me solve the issue?

here's my adapter:

```
public class MyLeaguesListAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyLeaguesListAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    List<MyContest> listItems;
    Context context;
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View v,int pos);

    }
    public MyLeaguesListAdapter(List<MyContest> listItems,Context context){
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_contest_item,parent,false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return myViewHolder;

    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public TextView leagueName,playerName,prizePool,playerRank,playerPoints,entryFee,spots;
        OnItemClickListener onItemCheckListener;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            leagueName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mc_contest_name);
            playerName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mc_player_name);
            prizePool = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mc_prize_pool);
            playerRank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mc_player_rank);
            playerPoints = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mc_player_points);
            entryFee = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mc_entry_fee);
            spots = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mc_spots);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        public void setItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener ic){
            this.onItemCheckListener = ic;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            this.onItemCheckListener.onItemClick(view,getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyContest listItem = listItems.get(position);
        holder.leagueName.setText(listItem.getLeaguename());
        holder.prizePool.setText(listItem.getPrizepool());
        holder.playerPoints.setText(listItem.getScore());
        holder.playerRank.setText(listItem.getRank());
        holder.playerName.setText(listItem.getUsername());
        holder.spots.setText(listItem.getSpots());
        holder.entryFee.setText(listItem.getFee());
        holder.setItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my *fragment*:

```
public class MyLeagues extends Fragment {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,ui;
    int score,userid,i=0;
    String username,lname,inviteCode;
     List<MyContest> list_item;
     MyLeaguesListAdapter adapter;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Sprite fadingCircle;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_leagues,null);
        ui = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("User",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        userid = ui.getInt("userid",-1);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.mcspin_kit);
        fadingCircle = new FadingCircle();
        progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(fadingCircle);
        Log.d("eede", "onCreateView: "+inviteCode);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mc_recycler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        list_item = new ArrayList<>();
        getMYContests();
        return view;
    }
    public void getMYContests(){
        Call<MyContestResponse> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance()
                .getApi()
                .getMycontests(userid);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MyContestResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MyContestResponse> call, Response<MyContestResponse> response) {
                list_item=response.body().getData();
                adapter = new MyLeaguesListAdapter(list_item,getContext());
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MyContestResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("bruv", "onFailure: "+t);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

error:

> 07-03 09:36:20.980 30095-30095/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>           Process: com.example.android.khelo, PID: 30095
>           android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:363)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6485)
>               at com.example.android.khelo.MyLeaguesListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyLeaguesListAdapter.java:75)
>               at com.example.android.khelo.MyLeaguesListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MyLeaguesListAdapter.java:20)

from what I've read, the issue is with the way I bind the `recylerview` but I've not got a clear idea about where the issue actually lies.

Comment: Post your model class of `MyContest`, error is happening while doing `setText` on `Textview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that one or many of your `listItem` attributes return an integer like `getScore` and `getFee`. So let's look at the implementation of `TextView.setText(int)`

```
public final void setText(int resid) {
     ...
}
```

As you can see, it only accepts the `int` as a resource id like `R.string.something`.
So what you can do here is to make your `int` become `string` when setText like

```
holder.playerPoints.setText(listItem.getScore().toString());
```

Comment: @AchuthGovind Glad to help, please accept my answer if it solves your issue :)